# OpenGL model rendering issue

Tags: opengl, java, lwjgl

Currently my game will not display models properly on my PC but they load right on a pc that supports openGL 3.0, and as my laptop only supports 2.1 the last model rendered will show properly but the ones before it lose there binded positions for the vertices. Using LWJGL and Java btw.

All my models are passed through a loader class and loaded to a vao. Here is how I store them in a VAO:

```
public RawModel loadToVAO(float[] positions, float[] textureCoords, float[] normals, int[] indices) {
    int vaoID = createVAO();
    bindIndicesBuffer(indices);
    storeDataInAttributeList(0, 3, positions);
    storeDataInAttributeList(1, 2, textureCoords);
    storeDataInAttributeList(2, 3, normals);
    unbindVAO();
    return new RawModel(vaoID, indices.length);
}
```

and here is what I am using to create the VAO, not I also have functional support for ARB if supported:

```
private int createVAO() {
    if (GLContext.getCapabilities().GL_ARB_vertex_array_object) {
        int vaoID = ARBVertexArrayObject.glGenVertexArrays();
        vaos.add(vaoID);
        ARBVertexArrayObject.glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
        return vaoID;
    } else {
        int vaoID = GL30.glGenVertexArrays();
        vaos.add(vaoID);
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(vaoID);
        return vaoID;
    }
}
```

and here is how I bind them and some other fun stuff:

```
private void storeDataInAttributeList(int attributeNumber, int coordinateSize, float[] data) {
    if (GLContext.getCapabilities().GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object) {
        int vboID = ARBVertexBufferObject.glGenBuffersARB();
        vbos.add(vboID);
        ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vboID);
        FloatBuffer buffer = storeDataInFloatBuffer(data);
        ARBVertexBufferObject.glBufferDataARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, buffer, ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
        if (GLContext.getCapabilities().GL_ARB_vertex_shader) {
            ARBVertexShader.glVertexAttribPointerARB(attributeNumber, coordinateSize, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        } else {
            GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(attributeNumber, coordinateSize, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        }
        ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, 0);
    } else {
        int vboID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        vbos.add(vboID);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        FloatBuffer buffer = storeDataInFloatBuffer(data);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
        if (GLContext.getCapabilities().GL_ARB_vertex_shader) {
            ARBVertexShader.glVertexAttribPointerARB(attributeNumber, coordinateSize, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        } else {
            GL20.glVertexAttribPointer(attributeNumber, coordinateSize, GL11.GL_FLOAT, false, 0, 0);
        }
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
    }
}

private void unbindVAO() {
    if (GLContext.getCapabilities().GL_ARB_vertex_array_object) {
        ARBVertexArrayObject.glBindVertexArray(0);
    } else {
        GL30.glBindVertexArray(0);
    }
}

private void bindIndicesBuffer(int[] indices) {
    if (GLContext.getCapabilities().GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object) {
        int vboID = ARBVertexBufferObject.glGenBuffersARB();
        vbos.add(vboID);
        ARBVertexBufferObject.glBindBufferARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, vboID);
        IntBuffer indicesBuffer = storeDataInIntBuffer(indices);
        ARBVertexBufferObject.glBufferDataARB(ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER_ARB, indicesBuffer, ARBVertexBufferObject.GL_STATIC_DRAW_ARB);
    } else {
        int vboID = GL15.glGenBuffers();
        vbos.add(vboID);
        GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboID);
        IntBuffer indicesBuffer = storeDataInIntBuffer(indices);
        GL15.glBufferData(GL15.GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, indicesBuffer, GL15.GL_STATIC_DRAW);
    }
}

private IntBuffer storeDataInIntBuffer(int[] data) {
    IntBuffer buffer = BufferUtils.createIntBuffer(data.length);
    buffer.put(data);
    buffer.flip();
    return buffer;
}

private FloatBuffer storeDataInFloatBuffer(float[] data) {
    FloatBuffer floatBuffer = BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(data.length);
    floatBuffer.put(data);
    floatBuffer.flip();
    return floatBuffer;
}
```

Here is a video of the issue I am having:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FJcTVu2eXQk

Here is my supported extensions on my pc

```
GL_EXT_blend_minmax
GL_EXT_blend_subtract 
GL_EXT_blend_color 
GL_EXT_abgr 
GL_EXT_texture3D 
GL_EXT_clip_volume_hint 
GL_EXT_compiled_vertex_array 
GL_SGIS_texture_edge_clamp 
GL_SGIS_generate_mipmap 
GL_EXT_draw_range_elements 
GL_SGIS_texture_lod 
GL_EXT_rescale_normal 
GL_EXT_packed_pixels 
GL_EXT_texture_edge_clamp 
GL_EXT_separate_specular_color 
GL_ARB_multitexture 
GL_EXT_texture_env_combine 
GL_EXT_bgra 
GL_EXT_blend_func_separate 
GL_EXT_secondary_color 
GL_EXT_fog_coord 
GL_EXT_texture_env_add 
GL_ARB_texture_cube_map 
GL_ARB_transpose_matrix 
GL_ARB_texture_env_add 
GL_IBM_texture_mirrored_repeat 
GL_EXT_multi_draw_arrays 
GL_NV_blend_square 
GL_ARB_texture_compression 
GL_3DFX_texture_compression_FXT1 
GL_EXT_texture_filter_anisotropic 
GL_ARB_texture_border_clamp 
GL_ARB_point_parameters 
GL_ARB_texture_env_combine 
GL_ARB_texture_env_dot3 
GL_ARB_texture_env_crossbar 
GL_EXT_texture_compression_s3tc 
GL_ARB_shadow 
GL_ARB_window_pos 
GL_EXT_shadow_funcs 
GL_EXT_stencil_wrap 
GL_ARB_vertex_program 
GL_EXT_texture_rectangle 
GL_ARB_fragment_program 
GL_EXT_stencil_two_side 
GL_ATI_separate_stencil 
GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object 
GL_EXT_texture_lod_bias 
GL_ARB_occlusion_query 
GL_ARB_fragment_shader 
GL_ARB_shader_objects 
GL_ARB_shading_language_100 
GL_ARB_texture_non_power_of_two 
GL_ARB_vertex_shader 
GL_NV_texgen_reflection 
GL_ARB_point_sprite 
GL_EXT_blend_equation_separate 
GL_ARB_depth_texture 
GL_ARB_texture_rectangle 
GL_ARB_draw_buffers 
GL_ARB_color_buffer_float 
GL_ARB_half_float_pixel 
GL_ARB_texture_float 
GL_ARB_pixel_buffer_object 
GL_EXT_framebuffer_object 
GL_ARB_draw_instanced 
GL_ARB_half_float_vertex 
GL_EXT_draw_buffers2 
GL_WIN_swap_hint 
GL_EXT_texture_sRGB
GL_EXT_packed_float 
GL_EXT_texture_shared_exponent 
GL_ARB_texture_rg 
GL_ARB_texture_compression_rgtc 
GL_NV_conditional_render 
GL_EXT_texture_swizzle 
GL_ARB_framebuffer_sRGB 
GL_EXT_packed_depth_stencil 
GL_ARB_depth_buffer_float 
GL_EXT_transform_feedback 
GL_EXT_framebuffer_blit 
GL_ARB_vertex_array_object
```

Comment: This does not appear to be a question.

Comment: How is it not a question? I am not sure why its not rendering on my laptop properly but it is for other users. My code seems to look good but I cant find an error and no one else seems to be either.

Comment: As @Trevor says, the content of the post does not contain any questions. (No sentences ending with a question mark...). It looks like you desire help debugging a fairly sizable slug of code... but not enough is included to actually try it at home. Best luck!

Comment: Ive posted my full source before and had my topic closed because it was two much to go through. [link](http://www.megafileupload.com/5ofy/Redwall_v30.rar) There is the full game source code for you though. The bottom block is functions my pc supports and not code. I included a video of my problem and described it in the title and I already told trevor what my issue is. I dont know what question to be asking because I cant find my problem and neither can anyone else. This problem only happens on older PCs not supporting opengl 3.0+ and I cannot get that on this PC and want my game to work on it